# better way to mass import unique contacts into sql (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to import a very large contact list (name & email in csv format, PHP -> MySQL).  I want to skip existing email.  My current method is very slow in a production DB, with a lot of data.

Assuming 100 contacts (may be 10,000 contacts)

Original Steps

1. got the input data
2. check each contact in the table for existing email

   - 100 select
3. mass insert in to the table

   - insert into value (), (), ()
   - 1 insert

This is slow.

I want to improve the process and time.

I have thought of 2 ways.

Method 1

1. create a max_addressbook_temp (same structure as max_addressbook) for temporary space
2. clear/delete all records for the user in max_addressbook_temp
3. insert all records in max_addressbook_temp
4. create a list of duplicated record (for front end)
5. insert unique records from max_addressbook_temp into max_addressbook

advantage

- can get a list of duplicated records to display in front end
- very fast - want to import 100 record, always need only 2 sql calls: 1 insert into values and 1 insert into select

disadvantage

- need a seperate table

Method 2

1. create unqiue index (book_user_name_id, book_email)
2. for each record, use insert ignore into ... (this will ignore duplicated book_user_name_id, book_email)

advantage

- less code

disadvantage

- can't display the contacts that are not imported
- slower, want to import 100 records, need to call 100 insert

Any feedback?  How are the most common & efficient way to importing a lot of addresses into DB?

=====

Here is more detail for method 1.  Do you think it is a good idea?

There are 4 steps.

- clear the temp data for the user
- insert the import data, not checking for duplicated
- selet the duplicated data for display or count
- insert data that are not duplicated

// clear the temp data for the user

```
delete max_addressbook_temp where book_user_id =
```

// insert the import data, not checking for duplicated

```
insert into max_addressbook_temp values (), (), ()....
```

// selet the duplicated data for display or count

```
select * from max_addressbook_temp t1, max_addressbook t2
where t1.book_user_id = t2.book_user_id
and t1.book_email = t2.book_email
```

// insert data that are not duplicated

```
insert into max_addressbook t1
select * from max_addressbook_temp t2
where t1.book_user_id = t2.book_user_id
and t1.book_email <> t2.book_email
```

Comment: The data is from a text field on a website in CSV format, i.e. name, email. I still like to display a list of contacts that are not imported, if possible and if it doesn't affect the speed too much.

Comment: You're not making a whole lot of sense. The answer below is a fine and correct method

Comment: @Strawberry I have a page on the site with a text box where a user can put  in a list of contact to import.  When a user clicks the import button, I process the list and import them into an address table. Then I display the number of contacts imported and NOT imported (duplicated).  I also display the list of contact that are NOT imported.  LOAD DATA import will not give me a list of contacts that are not imported, right?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Wny not use mySQL [BULK INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)?

EXAMPLE:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\MyTextFile'
INTO TABLE myDatabase.MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

ADDENDUM:

It sounds like you're actually asking two, separate, questions:

Q1: How do I read a .csv file into a mySQL database?

A: I'd urge you to consider [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

Q2: How do I "diff" the data in the .csv vs. the data already in mySQL (either intersection of rows in both; or the rows in one, but not the other)?

A: There is no "efficient" method.  Any way you do it, you're probably going to be doing a [full-table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan).

I would suggest the following:

1. Load your .csv data into a temp table
2. Do an [INTERSECT](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php) of the two tables:

   SELECT tableA.id
   FROM tableA
   WHERE tableA.id IN (SELECT id FROM tableB);
3. Save the results of your "intersect" query
4. Load the .csv data into your actual able

Comment: The data is from a text field on a website.  I still like to display a list of contacts that are not imported, if possible and if it doesn't affect the speed too much.

Comment: I have a page on the site with a text box where a user can put in a list of contact to import. When a user clicks the import button, I process the list and import them into an address table. Then I display the number of contacts imported and NOT imported (duplicated). I also display the list of contact that are NOT imported. LOAD DATA import will not give me a list of contacts that are not imported, right?

Comment: Please see my comments above.

Comment: The user enters (or copy & paste) the list in a text field on a web page.  There is not csv file upload.